# Grabbing most recent transaction/record

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having trouble creating a linq statement that would grab the most recent transaction that happened before the startdate specified. Was wondering if anyone can help me.

For example startdate is January 20st.

```
Id    LoanId    TransactionDate    InterestDate    Balance
1        5         January 5        January 3        5000
1        5         January 30       January 5        10000
2        5         January 22       January 22       4000
3        6         January 3        January 1        2000
```

I should have a list below

```
Id    LoanId    TransactionDate    InterestDate    Balance
1        5         January 5        January 3        5000
3        6         January 3        January 1        2000
```

I'm having trouble grouping by and grabbing the correct values.

```
var transactions =  ctx.Transactions.Where(x => x.Date <= startDate)
                    .GroupBy(x => x.LoanId)
                    .Select(x => new TransactionDTO
                    {
                        LoanId = ...
                        TransactionDate = ...
                        InterestDate = ....
                        Balance = ...
                    });
```

Comment: Let's see the query you're having trouble with then please. Is this Linq to SQL or Linq to Objects or...? Is the TransactionDate a DateTime object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be filtering by `startDate`, grouping by ID, ordering by `date`, and grabbing the first element of the group:

```
var res = tx
    .Where(tx => tx.TransactionDate <= startDate)
    .GroupBy(tx => tx.Id)
    .Select(g => g.OrderBy(tx => tx.Date).First());
```

Comment: This worked wonderfully, only think is it should be OrderByDescending.

Comment: Where is .Before() defined?

Comment: @StephenKennedy I did not see the edit with OP's code, so I offered a pseudocode-ish way of showing the concept. Thanks for the comment!